Is there any type of mechanical engine failure that would inhibit a helicopter from making an autorotation?
My understanding is that the motor shaft is connected to the rotor using some sort of clutch so that if the engine shuts down the helicopter rotor can keep spinning.
However I've heard of some fatal accidents with helicopters that happen after some sort of mechanical failure in the engine(like something breaks or something).
If someone can clarify this, my question is, is there in fact any type of failure in the engine that wouldn't allow the pilot to make an autorotation?

I could be totally wrong here, but I believe you need a certain minimum altitude to effectively autorotate.  If you experience an engine problem with insufficient altitude you  may not have enough time to auto rotate and wind up with a fatal crash as a result.

@ForwardEd   I'm not an expert but have looked at autorotation initiation. It needs to be initiated in the range 2-6 seconds MAXIMUM with this figure varying by aircraft. The Robinson R22 is one of the shortest. ASAP,  and under 2 seconds would be a VERY good idea. || The time avaiable is how long the rotor still spins with enough energy to pick up velocity again when pitch is fully reversed. If you leave it too long the rotor will not spin up and you fgall :-( . || Once you have changed pitch you are in autorotation. How long it takes for full spinup I know not. BUT see next comment ...

@ForwardEd What I said was (more or less) right BUT effectively misleading. The link below shows a safe height:velocity diagram for a Bell 204B. Aty zero forward velocity they recommend 800 feet altitude for entering safe autorotation, but at eg 55 knots its 75 feet. 204b: https://wiki2.org/en/Height-velocity_diagram || Robinson R22 video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=grvy3ft6uFI&t=1s

Some constraints are taken into account when designing the rotor transmission:

The clutch used to drive the rotor must be free-wheeling when the engine is malfunctioning and/or the autorotation is able to drive the rotor faster than the failed engine.
The clutch is a one-way coupling disengaging in case of engine failure.

The anti-torque rotor is directly coupled to the main rotor. Autorotation doesn't produce much torque but the anti-torque rotor is used to effectively yaw the helicopter.


Some helicopters are also equipped with a clutch preventing a slow engine to continue driving the rotor at a slow speed. This is to prevent the rotor to completely dissipates its kinetic energy before the pilot reacts to the engine failure and lowers the collective pitch to initiate the descent in autorotation.
Autorotation clutch: Relative difference of speeds




The autorotation clutch or sprag clutch only transmits drive one way. The dog bone-shaped elements
twist and lock between the inner and outer races to transmit the drive. If the relative drive direction reverses, the dog bones turn the other way and slip. Source: The Art of the Helicopter

Similarly on a twin-turbine helicopter, the coupling of the two engines is designed in a way one engine cannot prevent the other to drive the transmission alone. Each engine has its own one-way clutch:



Source: Ibid.
The only possibility for the rotors to be prevented to spin is the shaft/mast are jammed or broken, a possibility made unlikely by their sizes and their designs.
Centrifugal clutch: Fixed speed
In addition of the autorotation clutch(es), some helicopters have a centrifugal clutch preventing the rotor to be driven by the engine at low rpm. This clutch disconnects the main rotor shaft from the engine(s) as soon as the engine(s) is (are) not turning fast enough. This prevents the rotor losing its kinetic energy, the latter being helpful, sometimes necessary, to start the autorotation.
While the autorotation clutch disconnects the rotor as soon as the engine spins more slowly than the rotor (difference in speeds), the centrifugal clutch disconnects the rotor as soon as the rotor speed is below a fixed threshold, regardless of the engine speed.
See What is the purpose of a freewheeling unit in an helicopter, if a centrifugal clutch is already present?

In the crash of the second pre-production EH101, the failure mode did prevent autorotation. Not actually an engine problem, though
The control rods were destroyed by a fire started by frictional heat generated by a rotor brake problem.
https://web.archive.org/web/20120308214147/http://www.flightglobal.com/pdfarchive/view/1993/1993%20-%201144.html


That would have been a nasty feeling. (There must be a better way to put that :-( ). One can perhaps sort of accept accidents where you are at fault or another 'vehicle' is*, but having yuour machine just "stop flying properly" is not on.  || * I've been in two car vs motorbike accidents where the cars were at fault. Neither was very welcome, but on a motorbike it's an accepted risk.

